# removing the second matched word from a string?

Tags: javascript

I got a string

For example:

This is for trails and I want to learn Js and Coding and Development

The above mentioned line as a string

```js
function trail(sen){

var cat = "and"
var fin = sen.indexOf(cat);

 if(fin > 0){
  var last = sen.substring(0, fin)
  }
  else{
  var last = sen;
  }
  
return last;
}

console.log(
  trail("This is for trails and I want to learn Js and Coding and Development ")
);
```

I am trying to find the index of the second "and" in a string rather than the first one.

and get the string part from index 0 to that second "and"

Could you please provide the better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` together with `join` to achieve this, like so:

```js
const myStr = 'This is for trails and I want to learn Js and Coding and Development'
const subStr = 'and'

const splitted = getSplitted(myStr, subStr, 2)  // Splits before the "N th" ocurrence of subStr

console.log(splitted)

function getSplitted(str, subStr, idx) {
  return str.split(subStr, idx).join(subStr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the second occurrence and then remove it via simple `slice`.
This method also supports regular expressions as pattern.

```js
/**
 * Find the n-th occurrence of given pattern in a string.
 * @param { string } str The string to be examined.
 * @param { string | RegExp } pattern The pattern to be matched.
 * @param { number } n Starting index.
 * @return { [number, string | RegExpExecArray] } The index & the match result. `[-1, null]` if pattern occurs less than n times.
 */
function findNth(str, pattern, n = 1) {
    // The total processed index & and the last match
    let index = 0, result;
    for(; n--; ) {
        // Index of the next match relative to the end of the last one
        let offset = -1;
        if(pattern instanceof RegExp) {
            const match = pattern.exec(str);
            if(match !== null) {
                offset = match.index;
                result = match[0];
            }
        }
        else {  // string case
            offset = str.indexOf(pattern);
            result = pattern;
        }
        // If none is matched
        if(offset === -1)
            return [-1, null];
        // Seek over the match result
        offset += result.length;
        str = str.slice(offset);
        index += offset;
    }
    // Gotta go back to the start of the last match
    index -= result.length;
    return [index, result];
}

/** Remove the n-th occurrence of given pattern out of a string. */
function removeNth(str, pattern, n = 1) {
    const result = findNth(str, pattern, n);
    if(result[0] === -1)
        return str;
    return str.slice(0, result[0]) + str.slice(result[0] + result[1].length);
}

{
    const str = 'This is for trails and I want to learn Js and Coding and Development';
    console.log(removeNth(str, 'and', 2));
    console.log(removeNth(str, /\s*and/, 2));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I also removing the part after second occurrence of "and"

Comment: Notice that with the support for `RegExp`, you can correctly handle the pre- and post-fixing spaces around a word, without leaving two spaces joined together awkwardly.

Comment: thanks so much for your insights , really love the approach

Answer (score 0):

Use `split`

```
sen.split(cat, 2) // This line will divide the syntax into an array of two elements till second "and" occurrence

// ['This is for trails ', ' I want to learn Js ']
```

Then you need to join them to add the first and

```
sen.split(cat, 2).join(cat)
```

And to get the length

```
sen.split(cat, 2).join(cat).length
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "This is for trails and I want to learn Js and Coding and Development".split("and", 2).join("");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: this is omitting both the and's in the string

Comment: you are removing both the "and"